# printing with out showing UI in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing

I could find some code for skipping the Printing UI and direct print through the Air Printer.But the code was incomplete. The code is below,

```
UIPrinterPickerController *printPicker = [UIPrinterPickerController printerPickerControllerWithInitiallySelectedPrinter:self.savedPrinter];
    [printPicker presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:
        ^(UIPrinterPickerController *printerPicker, BOOL userDidSelect, NSError *error) {
        if (userDidSelect) {
            self.savedPrinter = printerPicker.selectedPrinter;
        }
    }];
```

In this code, self.savedPrinter mentioned. But how can i get the saved printer here. Please give me a complete answer or sample solution for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925387/skipping-the-printing-ui-in-ios-8

Comment: I have used that code in ipad its not working

Comment: I find the solution. thank you Muhammad.